# How many Meteor apps can you run on 1 server?

Tags: meteor, server

I'm currently running 4 Meteor apps (and planning to host much more) on 1 server with the following specs:

- Intel® Xeon® E3-1230v3 4x3,3 GHz
- 32 GB RAM

Which is running great. But I wonder how far I can go? All the Meteor apps I host have about 200 - 300 visitors each per month and are portfolio websites.

Would I be able to run 100 Meteor apps on this server? 200? 300? 10?

Answer (score 1):

On my server, a simple meteor app takes 350-400mb of ram.
Yeah... i know that's not a lot of information but maybe it could help.

For me the limitation is mostly RAM usage.

For CPU i haven't noticed almost anything. Depends what computation's are done on the server.

About visitors, NodeJS is made this way so it can handle 10k simultaneous clients on a web server.
[node.js concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215972/node-js-concurrency)

Meteor also need some RAM for each client that is subscribed to some DB collection.

I would suggest you this : 
(400mb * apps.length) / 32gb = x

Hope it helped.

Comment: I just checked how much RAM and CPU usage my apps use and 400 MB per app sounds about right. Thanks!